# What could be an example of a Vector Field that is smooth but unconservative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Given that a vector field $X$ is smooth in $\mathbb{R}^2$, what could be an example of an unconservative vector field following said property? I was thinking about $X=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$, however I don't think it is considered as a smooth vector field as it is undefined at $(0,0)$. Are there any examples of that?

Comment: As long as the vector field $(f_1,f_2)$ fails to satisfy the Poincaré lemma condition $\partial f_1/\partial y=\partial f_2/\partial x$ it will not be conservative. Pick $(y^2,x^2)$ for example.

Comment: If I understand the conditions for a vector field to be smooth, wouldn't vector field $X=(y^2,x^2)$ not be smooth? (as it needs to satisfy: $X(t)≠zero vector$ for all values of t in domain)

Comment: Of course it's smooth. There's no requirement for the vector field to be nonzero.

Comment: Hans is right, but even if he was wrong, you can just consider $(1+y^2,x^2)$.